# Robotium + Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robotium, robolectric

I am using both frameworks to test my application.

I know these commands to run each:

Instrumentaion:    `gradlew clean connectedAndroidTest`
Robolectric   :    `gradlew clean build`

I have tried others, but these are the points in my opinion.

Are there any command to run both tests?

Comment: Have you tried ./gradlew clean build connectedAndroidTest ?

Comment: No, but I will try it :)   (good ideia)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to run all tests:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Or this to run single testcase:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.foo.FooTest com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

**More info how to use here**: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html)

Here is example how I'm using this command

```
adb shell am instrument -w  -e class app.name.androidTest.TestCustomer mobile.touch.core.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

It's great becouse it runs test immediately

**Another way is implementing** [spoon-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin) Spoon plugin is great for running test and generating reports.

Command to run test with spoon:

```
gradle spoon -PspoonClassName=fully.qualified.TestCase
```